# Getting error: RPC prog. not avail while trying to mount using nfs

Tags: macos, mount, nfs

On my Raspbian jessie I have NFS **server** running:

```
 $ sudo service rpcbind status
● rpcbind.service - LSB: RPC portmapper replacement
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/rpcbind)
  Drop-In: /run/systemd/generator/rpcbind.service.d
           └─50-rpcbind-$portmap.conf
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2016-09-19 18:33:01 UTC; 2min 17s ago
  Process: 9800 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/rpcbind start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/rpcbind.service
           └─9809 /sbin/rpcbind -w

Sep 19 18:33:01 raspberrypi rpcbind[9800]: Starting rpcbind daemon....
Sep 19 18:33:01 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started LSB: RPC portmapper replacement
```

and on my **client** machine mac

I am trying to mount *the shared drive*

```
$ sudo mount -o rsize=32768,wsize=32768,intr,noatime -t nfs 192.168.1.100:/home/pi/USBHDD /Volumes/USBHDD
mount_nfs: can't mount /home/pi/USBHDD from 192.168.1.100 onto /Volumes/USBHDD: RPC prog. not avail
```

Comment: Can you use `mount -v` and add the output to the question? Also I assume that you did export `USBHDD` on your Raspbian and that the local `USBHDD` directory existis, correct?

Comment: Are you really using `*` after the IP address when you run the command? And where do you get the error mentioned in the title, it doesn't show up in the question itself?

Comment: @patrix yes USBHDD exists at both client and server

Comment: @patrix : sorry i missed pasting the complete text , I have updated it now.

Comment: What does `rpcinfo -p 192.168.1.100` show? See also: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1356126?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: tried that already: `$ rpcinfo -p 192.168.1.100
   program vers proto   port
    100000    4   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    4   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   udp    111  portmapper
    100003    4   tcp   2049  nfs
    100003    4   udp   2049  nfs`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/nfs-kernel-server restart
```

Answer (score 0):

I received this error message on the *client* side when the NFS server had crashed.  It was resolved by

```
sudo systemctl restart nfs-server
```

on the *server* side

Answer (score 0):

I received this error message on the client side when `firewalld` was blocking the `mountd` port on the server side. I could imagine this happening when `firewalld` was also blocking the port assigned to `nfs`. To remediate this issue, I added a new `firewalld` exception. Since the `mountd` port was dynamically generated (I didn't set the value in `/etc/sysconfig/nfs` as recommended [here](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/14/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/s2-nfs-nfs-firewall-config.html) and [here](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/18/html/Security_Guide/sect-Security_Guide-Securing_NFS-NFS_Firewall_Configuration.html)), I had to find which port to add an exception for. [This document](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/14/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/s2-nfs-nfs-firewall-config.html) relates the command to use is `rpcbind -p`, and then search for `mountd`. In my case, this turned out to be port 20048. Finally, I made sure that all the ports were allowed through `firewalld`. Since nfs needs rpc, I allowed port 111 (both TCP and UDP), port 2049 (both TCP and UDP), and port 20048 (both TCP and UDP).

I'm not totally sure on how to do that last step on Raspbian (and I doubt you care, since my answer is almost four years too late), but that might get you up and running.

---

I noticed that you put the output of `rpcinfo` in the comments to your answer, so I'll include my "after" image for `rpcinfo` pointing at my server.

```
> rpcinfo -p 192.168.1.73
      program vers proto   port
       100000    4   tcp    111  rpcbind
       100000    3   tcp    111  rpcbind
       100000    2   tcp    111  rpcbind
       100000    4   udp    111  rpcbind
       100000    3   udp    111  rpcbind
       100000    2   udp    111  rpcbind
       100024    1   udp  44606  status
       100024    1   tcp  43709  status
       100005    1   udp  20048  mountd
       100005    1   tcp  20048  mountd
       100005    2   udp  20048  mountd
       100005    2   tcp  20048  mountd
       100005    3   udp  20048  mountd
       100005    3   tcp  20048  mountd
       100003    3   tcp   2049  nfs
       100003    4   tcp   2049  nfs
       100227    3   tcp   2049  nfs_acl
       100021    1   udp  46387  nlockmgr
       100021    3   udp  46387  nlockmgr
       100021    4   udp  46387  nlockmgr
       100021    1   tcp  36435  nlockmgr
       100021    3   tcp  36435  nlockmgr
       100021    4   tcp  36435  nlockmgr
```