# Not able to connect to NFS server from my MacBook

Tags: network, macos, nfs, client

I have an NFS server running remotely on my network, but I am not able to connect to it.

I am using NFS Manager  which shows this information:

[image: NFS Manager test result]

but getting the below error:

[image: Error message]

Answer (score 1):

Does it work when you use the `mount` command? For example, I can mount my NetBoot server's NFS export with:

```
sudo mkdir /Volumes/nfsmount
sudo mount -t nfs 192.168.1.8:/Volumes/Data/Library/NetBoot/NetBootSP0 /Volumes/nfsmount/
```

Comment: I have tried that already failing to which I installed this NFS Manager see : http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/253447/64918